# Linux Device Driver Create Data Buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, allocation

I am working on developing a Linux driver for a matrix multiplication accelerator. The accelerator loads entries into its scratchpad given a base pointer. The problem, of course, is that user applications do not use the physical pointers of the memory and the base pointer is a virtual address. Is there an elegant way for the driver allocate contiguous memory and give the user space application a virtual pointer?

Comment: First of all it’s better to use specific framework inside the Linux kernel. And for a such the closest is GPU.

Comment: Closer to your problem I would suggest to look into existing (in the kernel or public mailing lists) drivers like habana labs or GNA (Intel).

Comment: The driver can implement the `mmap` file operation to map some kernel buffer memory into userspace.

Comment: @IanAbbott That makes sense, but, as I understand it, mmap requires a base physical address. Is there a way I can have this allocated instead?

Comment: What makes you think mmap ever uses physical addresses?

Comment: @stark I have successfully been able to map physical addresses to virtual address using it

Comment: Please show your code.